# Insert Cite element in HTML using javascript dom

Tags: javascript

I want to add a cite element with a text and href in the footer tag which is present in the HTML but is empty (currently)

I am using this code but its not working.

```
let cite = document.createElement("cite");
cite.setAttribute("text","Information and photos from Wikipedia");
cite.setAttribute("href", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumblebee");
let ftr = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];
ftr.innerHTML(cite);
```

Code of the HTML page where I wish to insert the dom element is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE OTHER THAN REFERENCING THE SCRIPT FILE -->

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Assignment 5a</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Bumblebee</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
    <h2>General description</h2>

    <figure><img src="bee1.jpg" />
      <figcaption>A common bumblebee extending its tongue towards a Heuchera inflorescence.
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <p>Bumblebees  beast".</p>


    <h2>Distribution and habitat</h2>

    <figure><img src="bee2.jpg" />
      <figcaption>Cuckoo bumblebees have similar warning coloration to
        nest-making bumblebees.</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <p>Bumblebees t pollinators.</p>
  </main>
  <footer>

  </footer>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please note that I cannot use HTML tag in JS file and document.write

Comment: What about `ftr.appendChild(cite)` instead?

Comment: im trying to add the cite element to footer tag

Comment: Something like this document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].appendChild= cite;

Comment: no that won’t work. Please may you try using my suggestion?

Comment: ftr.appendChild(cite) is not working

Comment: do you see an error?

Comment: No errors but i did a mistake.  i want to add the text to the cite tag but I added the attribute. how to rectify it??

Comment: let cite = document.createElement("cite");
cite.setAttribute("href", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumblebee");
Information and photos from Wikipedia
const ftr = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];
ftr.appendChild(cite);

Comment: Only one thing is left, The footer cite tag is not visible because I have to give the name to it.

Comment: Tried this code also [code] let cite = document.createElement("cite");
cite.setAttribute("href", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumblebee");
let text = document.createTextNode("Information and photos from Wikipedia");
cite.appendChild(text);
const ftr = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];
ftr.appendChild(cite);[code]

Comment: Please see my answer for a working runnable snippet example of what I think you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close.

This example uses `cite.textContent =`  to set the content of the `cite` element instead of setting an attribute called "text".

It also uses `ftr.appendChild(cite)` to add the `cite` element to the `ftr` footer element. This is because `innerHTML` does not take DOM elements, but an HTML string instead. So `ftr.innerHTML = '<span>hello world</span'` would work, but `ftr.innerHTML = cite` does not.

```js
let cite = document.createElement("cite");
cite.textContent = "Information and photos from Wikipedia";
cite.setAttribute("href", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumblebee");
let ftr = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];
ftr.appendChild(cite);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE OTHER THAN REFERENCING THE SCRIPT FILE -->

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Assignment 5a</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Bumblebee</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
    <h2>General description</h2>

    <figure><img src="bee1.jpg" />
      <figcaption>A common bumblebee extending its tongue towards a Heuchera inflorescence.
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <p>Bumblebees beast".</p>


    <h2>Distribution and habitat</h2>

    <figure><img src="bee2.jpg" />
      <figcaption>Cuckoo bumblebees have similar warning coloration to nest-making bumblebees.</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <p>Bumblebees t pollinators.</p>
  </main>
  <footer>

  </footer>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```